# Unknown error for jquery ajax data return in json

Tags: jquery, json, ajax

I am trying get json values from a database using an ajax jquery with php.
My code....
  Currently i didn't get any error and i had tried already [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call) this link before posted over here. i didn't get data in return value while i have added using it in ajax,

--------------------code 1-------------------

```
   $.ajax({
     type: "Post",
     url: site_url + "admin/venue_booking_list/" + val,
     //dataType: 'html',
     data: {
         van_id: val
     },
     async: true,
     cache: false,
     //dataType: 'json',
     success: function(data) {
         return [{
             "title": "Booked",
             "start": "19-01-2016 08:00:00",
             "end": "19-01-2016 08:30:00",
             "backgroundColor": "#12CA6B",
             "textColor": "#FFF"
         }, {
             "title": "Booked",
             "start": "19-01-2016 08:00:00",
             "end": "19-01-2016 08:30:00",
             "backgroundColor": "#12CA6B",
             "textColor": "#FFF"
         }, {
             "title": "Booked",
             "start": "04-01-2016 08:00:00",
             "end": "04-01-2016 08:30:00",
             "backgroundColor": "#12CA6B",
             "textColor": "#FFF"
         }, {
             "title": "Booked",
             "start": "01-01-2016 07:30:00",
             "end": "01-01-2016 08:00:00",
             "backgroundColor": "#12CA6B",
             "textColor": "#FFF"
         }, {
             "title": "Booked",
             "start": "13-01-2016 07:30:00",
             "end": "13-01-2016 08:00:00",
             "backgroundColor": "#12CA6B",
             "textColor": "#FFF"
         }];
     }
 });

 }
```

-------------code 2 ----------------------

```
 $.ajax({
        type: "Post",
        url: site_url + "admin/venue_booking_list/" + val,
        //dataType: 'html',
        data: {
            van_id: val

        },
        async: true,
        cache: false,
        //dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {

            // removed code

        }
        return [{
            "title": "Booked",
            "start": "19-01-2016 08:00:00",
            "end": "19-01-2016 08:30:00",
            "backgroundColor": "#12CA6B",
            "textColor": "#FFF"
        }, {
            "title": "Booked",
            "start": "19-01-2016 08:00:00",
            "end": "19-01-2016 08:30:00",
            "backgroundColor": "#12CA6B",
            "textColor": "#FFF"
        }, {
            "title": "Booked",
            "start": "04-01-2016 08:00:00",
            "end": "04-01-2016 08:30:00",
            "backgroundColor": "#12CA6B",
            "textColor": "#FFF"
        }, {
            "title": "Booked",
            "start": "01-01-2016 07:30:00",
            "end": "01-01-2016 08:00:00",
            "backgroundColor": "#12CA6B",
            "textColor": "#FFF"
        }, {
            "title": "Booked",
            "start": "13-01-2016 07:30:00",
            "end": "13-01-2016 08:00:00",
            "backgroundColor": "#12CA6B",
            "textColor": "#FFF"
        }];
```

In the first of the 2 code snippets when data is retrieved from the database it doesnt show in console bar as Object json, as in the following image.
[image] 
[image]

How can I get a result like the second image, where there is static code in the js file, as shown in code2?

Please Help

Comment: where are you trying to `return` to? Using `return` in the `success` function does nothing ... consume the data there instead

Comment: sorry but i didnt get you , i want to objects as shown in second img . can you please tell me what i need to use.becuase data need to came thorugh using ajax

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: no i have already tried your given link but that was not work ok, my question is how to add json in return value while i have added this code directly from static code it work perfect

Comment: The duplicate will show you how to do it. You can't return anything from the AJAX call, because it is asynchronous.